# Show a progress Bar when Rewarded video Ads is loading

Tags: java, android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I want to use Rewarded video ads (Admob) but I want to show a progress bar while the video ads is loading
I already try to did it with **async task** just to see if the video will load but it didn't work

```
     @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public class videoAd extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
            super.onPostExecute(integer);
            if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()){

                Toast.makeText(SetFullWallpaper.this, "Video loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to load a progress bar if the video is not loaded yet
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I did it:

I had a button, which when clicked showed the ad, so I had a boolean variable which tracked whether the button has been clicked:

```
boolean buttonClicked = false
```

These lines were in my onCreate function:

```
    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(getContext());
    rewardedVideoAdListener = new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
            if(buttonClicked) {
                showAd();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
            loadRewardedVideoAd();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            if(buttonClicked) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {

        }
    };

    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(rewardedVideoAdListener);

    loadRewardedVideoAd();

    pointsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showAd();
            }
        });
```

This was my showAd function:

```
public void showAd(){
    if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
        buttonClicked = false;
    } else {
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonClicked = true;
    }
}
```

How this works is, the app tries to load the ad in the background by calling the `loadRewaredVideoAd()` function when the activity/fragment is created. Then when the user clicks the button,`showAd()` function is called and one of two things happen:

- 1) If the ad was successfully loaded, it shows the ad.
- 2) If not, it calls `loadRewardedVideoAd()` again and shows a progressbar this time. It also sets `buttonClicked` to true. Then if the ad loads, the `onRewardedVideoAdLoaded()` function is called which calls `showAd()` again and this time the 1st option happens. 
  If the ad didn't load this time as well, then `onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i)`is called and it shows a toast saying the user to try again later.

Answer (score 0):

add OnProgressUpdate() in your class that extends AsyncTask and add progress dialog in this.

Answer (score 0):

I am placing an admob video, which is executed when you enter the activity. In my case, I put an executable loop to start the video when it is already loaded.

```
if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
    }else{
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }
```

This is part of all my code

```
private boolean started = false;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private void initializeAdMob() {
    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}

private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    if (!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(getString(R.string.id_block_activity), new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}

private void showRewardedVideoAd() {
    if (BaseInteractor.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
        showProgressBar(true);
        start();
    }
}

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
            mRewardedVideoAd.show();
        }else{
            loadRewardedVideoAd();
        }
        if (started) {
            start();
        }
    }
};

public void stop() {
    started = false;
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

public void start() {
    started = true;
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
}
```

finally I stop the runnable in

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    showProgressBar(false);
    stop();
}
```

I hope this helps you.